# Setting IDs for JournalEntry or Invoice

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to insert an invoice, credit memo, and invoice using IPP.Net.  How do I know what the AccountID, ClassID, or EntityID is?  When I used the Web Connector to write a previous interface, I was able to specify these things by FullName.  Do I need to do some type of query to get all of the IDs for future use?  If I do that, will the IDs ever change through any processes, such as re-indexing, or is the ID permanent?

Answer (score 1):

**If you're integrating with QuickBooks Online:**

Yes, the IPP APIs for QuickBooks Online only accept Id values. You will have to [query for the objects](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0030_Retrieving_Objects) so that you can get their Id values to use them in future invoice/credit memo add requests.

**If you're integrating with QuickBooks for Windows:**

The IPP APIs for QuickBooks desktop for Windows can accept either Name values, or Id values. So you could either [query](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0015_Retrieving_Objects) to get the Id values, or just use the Names like you do in the SDK.

**A few things worth noting:**

The next version of data services Intuit is releasing (v3) will likely be released summer/fall 2013. v3 data services will *only accept Id values* like QuickBooks Online does in v2. So, if you want to plan ahead for the future, start querying. :-)

Regarding this:

> If I do that, will the IDs ever change through any processes, such as re-indexing, or is the ID permanent?

The Id values are permanent - they should never change. *The one exception to this* is if something gets really fubar'd on Intuit's end and they reset someone's Sync Manager to force QuickBooks to sync to a new online realm. But this generally shouldn't happen in production.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  This will guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I am trying to check the class list at http://docs.developer.intuit.com/IntuitDataServicesSDK to see what classes and methods are available for querying, but the class list page indicates that it is broken.  Any ideas on when it will be fixed?

Comment: Heidi - Since that's clearly an issue with Intuit's website, you should probably put in a support ticket with Intuit. I don't work for Intuit, so I have absolutely no idea when they're going to fix their website.

Comment: Sorry.  I was a little confused about your role.  I will do that.

Comment: I have been successful in querying a list of accounts using the Account class as well as retrieving a single account by account name using AccountQuery.  However, none of the lists show the ID when I bind the list to a grid.  What is the best way to get the ID for an account?

Comment: If they don't show the Id value, then you must not be binding the Id value to the grid, or something else is wrong. The XML requests you make to Intuit's service will very definitely return the Id value. Post up your code if you're still having trouble.

Comment: I am binding to a Gridview using autogenerate.  Therefore, I would think that it would give me all of the available properties.  Here is my code:

Comment: Here is my VB code: <br/>Dim AccountQuery as New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery  AccountQuery.Name="Markup"  Dim qboAccounts as IEnumerable(Of Intuit.App.Data.Qbo.Account) = AccountQuery.ExecuteQuery(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account)(context)< gv_Accounts.Datasource=qboAccounts  gv_Accounts.Databind()<br/><br/>In my aspx file, I have<br/><asp:Gridview id="gv_Accounts" runat="server"></asp:Gridview>  This returns several properties, but not ID.  (Sorry about the formatting.  I am new to this.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things, and I seem to have found the answer.  The Id property does not bind on its own through Autogenerate of the gridview.  That seems to be because it is a class and not a simple property.  You have to specifically bind Id.value.